# Html TypeProvider MSBuild compilation issue

Tags: f#, msbuild, type-providers, f#-data

I am using multiple type providers two of them HTML type providers. Everything compiles using Visual Studio, however when using MSBuild one of the html type providers does not generate the type system and I will get errors such as:

> FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to
>   this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object.
>
> FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Descendants' is not defined (while accessing the Descendants collection of the Html property).

Both of these errors are probably just caused by the fact that the type provider does not generate the types correctly when building with MsBuild.

Are there any parameters specific to Visual Studio/MsBuild which would affect type providers? It seems that this is linked to the HTML file itself, because as said it works with other files, but I don't see any reason why it works in VS and does not work using MsBuild.

Comment: Are you pointing the type provider to a local file or a URL?

Comment: the type provider is pointed to local file which is included as Embedded Resource. Both HTML providers that I am using have the same configuration - and only one does not work when building with MsBuild